# WPF MVVM Databinding with parameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

So my previous question seem to not be answerable, so i'm going to give this a go with a suggestion of my own.

The functionality im looking for, is having a datagrid change the Foreground (or even background) of a cell, when the data in that cell has been edited.

My Model looks something like this:

```
Public class Shipment : PropertyChangedBase
{
    #region Fields
    private ShippingService.Shipment.lbnshipment _localShipment;
    private ShippingService.Shipment.lbnshipment _originalShipment;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int ShipmentID
    {
        get { return _localShipment.ShipmentID; }
        set
        {
            if(value != _localShipment.ShipmentID)
            {
                _localShipment.ShipmentID = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShipmentID);
            }
         }
    } 

    public Shipment(ShippingServices.Shipment.lbnShipment localshipment)
    {
        _originalShipment = localshipment;
        _localShipment = localshipment;
    }

    //This Section is my best guess solution, but it just a guess
    public Color HasChanged(string Property)
    {
        switch(Property)
        {
           case "ShipmentID":
               if(_localShipment.ShipmentID != _originalShipment.ShipmentID)
               {
                  return Colors.Red;
               } else {
                  return Colors.Black;
               }
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've obviously stripped out most of the properties, and the HasChanged right now is pure myth, but what i'm hoping for is that somehow, i can bind a DataGridTextColumn Foreground(or background hopefully) to this HasChanged method, and somehow pass it which paramater is currently calling the method.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ShipmentID" Binding="{Binding ShipmentID}" Foreground="{Binding HasChanged}" />
```

I'm hoping there is some clever way for me to allow the binding to identify which property has changed, much in the same way that IDataErrorInfo allows validation to be bound per property. Although i have no idea how that actually functions in the background.

Comment: You could use a `IMultiValueConverter` and bind the property from your current view-model and a property from copy of this view-model. Then validate inside the converter if the properties are equal and return the specific color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It calls out for a converter, no? So your binding would look like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Foreground>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Converter={StaticResource hasChangedConverter}, ConverterParameter='ShipmentID'}"/>
</DataGridTextColumn.Foreground>
```

And your converter would look like (stripping extraneous code):

```
class HasChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var shipment = value as Shipment;
        var property = parameter as string;

        return shipment.HasChanged(property);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Using single quotes on the converter parameter as shown above ought to work. Failing that, you can use the extended format for the binding:

```
<SolidColorBrush.Color>
    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource hasChangedConverter}" ConverterParameter="ShipmentID"/>
</SolidColorBrush.Color>
```

UPDATE II:
... and obviously we can't go around changing the background of `DataGridTextColumn`s, so change your column's XAML to something like the following:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ShipmentID">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShipmentID}">
                <TextBlock.Background> 
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ShipmentID, Converter={StaticResource HasChangedConv}}"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Would the value at this point not actually be the string property "ShipmentID" rather than the shipment object itself?

Comment: if you wrote `Foreground="{Binding ShipmentID, Converter=...}"` then, yes it would. Omit the `ShipmentID` part and that won't be a problem.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a try, its a much cleaner solution than I had :D

Comment: dooh! passing string literals as converter parameters isn't done the way I showed. I'll update the answer. In the meantime, this link is helpful:
http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/04/wpf_passing_string_to_converte.html

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the update, also just to note that the Foreground does not take a color it takes a brush. thats my oops :D

Comment: I'm getting an error when using this latest update, typing text now dosnt draw, and the following error is in output:
Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=63303930); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

Comment: That is an error I've never seen before. Are you returning a SolidColorBrush from your converter or a color? When is the exception getting thrown?

Comment: I now return a new SolidColorBrush from the converter. a quick google showed that you cannot dynamically change a SolidColorBrushes color. but i now get a very similar Cannot find governing FrameworkElement error. although the text can be seen, it always remains black. and it's thrown whenever you edit the cell

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47501/discussion-between-user1412240-and-mcwyrm)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- If this `Property` thing is in UI binded to the ViewModel You can listen on changes of that property in the `ViewModel` and then changed the color accordingly.
- If not, use the Command System. The ideal scenario would be:  
   - The UI sends a `Command` to the `ViewModel` that something has changed. 
   - The `ViewModel` executes the command, and changes the `Color` field. UI needs to be informed that the color has changed.

Here's an implementation of ICommand interface:

http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm actually using CM for this, so command are easy, however this would mean having a color property for every single property (baring in mind shipment has 30 properties, and when i say property i mean, ShipmentID, ShipmentNO etc). I was hoping for a solution that would avoid having so many extra properties on the model/viewmodel.